# Can I vectorise/vectorize this simple cohort retention model in R?

Tags: r, vectorization, retention

I am creating a simple cohort-based user retention model, based on the number of new users that appear each day, and the likelihood of a user reappearing on day 0 (100%), day 1, day 2, etc.  I want to know the number of users active on each day.   I am trying to vectorise this and getting in a right muddle.    Here is a toy mockup.

```
rvec <- c(1, .8, .4);   #retention for day 0, 1,2 (day 0 = 100%, and so forth)
newvec <- c(10, 10, 10); #new joiners for day 0, 1, 2  (might be different)
playernumbers <- matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 3);

# I want to fill matrix playernumbers  such that sum of each row gives 
# the total playernumbers on day rownumber-1
# here is a brute force method  (could be simplified via a loop or two)
# but what I am puzzled about is whether there is a way to fully vectorise it    
playernumbers[1,1] <- rvec[1] * newvec[1];
playernumbers[2,1] <- rvec[2] * newvec[1];
playernumbers[3,1] <- rvec[3] * newvec[1];
playernumbers[2,2] <- rvec[1] * newvec[2];
playernumbers[3,2] <- rvec[2] * newvec[2];
playernumbers[3,3] <- rvec[1] * newvec[3];
playernumbers
```

I can't figure out how to vectorise this fully.   I can see how I might do it columnwise,  successsively using each  column number to indicate (a) which rows to update (column number: nrows), and (b) which newvec index value to multiply by.  But I'm not sure this is worth doing, as to me the loop is clearer.   But is there a fully vectorised form am I missing?  thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that I've understood correct, so I'm only commenting, but perhaps this could help: `apply(diag(newvec), 2, cummax) * matrix(c(rvec, 0), length(rvec), length(newvec))`

Comment: thanks alexis!   another one for my "to diagram to that I understand it" collection ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't insist on your weird indexing logic, you could simply calculate the outer product:

```
outer(rvec, newvec)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   10   10   10
#[2,]    8    8    8
#[3,]    4    4    4
```

In the outer product the product of the second element of vector 1 and the second element of vector 2 is placed at [2,2]. You place it at [3,2]. Why?

Your result:

```
playernumbers
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   10    0    0
#[2,]    8   10    0
#[3,]    4    8   10
```

**Edit:**

This should do the same as your loop:

```
rvec <- c(1, .8, .4)   
newvec <- c(10, 20, 30)

tmp <- outer(rvec, newvec)
tmp <- tmp[, ncol(tmp):1]
tmp[lower.tri(tmp)] <- 0
tmp <- tmp[, ncol(tmp):1]
res <- tmp*0
res[lower.tri(res, diag=TRUE)] <- tmp[tmp!=0]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   10    0    0
#[2,]    8   20    0
#[3,]    4   16   30

rowSums(res)
#[1] 10 28 50
```

Comment: Aside from the ordering mess, you could get his triangular result by calling `lower.tri(playernumbers,diag=TRUE)`

Comment: The semantics of the situation are that every day new users join, and the rate at which they revisit drops off day by day.   So my row 1 shows people visiting, who are all born on Day 1.   Row 2, shows the people born on day 1 revisiting with p = rvec[2], plus a new crop of joiners, for total user numbers of 18.  And so forth.  What Roland and Carl are calling "weird indexing logic" and "ordering mess" actually reflects the semantics of the situation correctly.   What I am looking for is a more R vectorised way of expressing this.  I do not see how the outer product computes what I need.

Comment: n.b. if you mean my use of day 0 as weird indexing, this is traditional in the literature but we can forget about it if it is misleading

Comment: Thanks Roland!  (I need to study it and work it through with a diagram before I get it totally but it looks good!)